# how to fix null dereference issue

Tags: java

Fortify is giving `null` dereference error in the following code. can any one suggest me how to fix it,

Thanks in advance.

```
public byte[] toByteArray(Notification nd) throws EmailProviderException {

    String message = null;

    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(nd.getClass());
        if (jc != null) {
            Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            m.marshal(nd, sw);
            message = sw.toString();
        }

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new EmailProviderException("Unable to convert NDS notification to byte array.", e);
    }

    return message.getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Which line? Anyway, one or more of these is/are `null`: `nd`, `jc`, `m`, `sw`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is in

```
Notification nd
```

You are passing this variable and after that you use

```
nd.getClass()
```

Try to create new instance of Notification before you use it:

```
Notification nd = new ...
toByteArray(nd)
```